# Compute line integral using properties of Green's theorem.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Line integral of $$\frac{-y^3}{(x^2+y^2)^2} dx + \frac{xy^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} dy$$

where the line is boundary of any simply connected region that contains the unit disk centered about the origin.

Since the line is arbitrary, I am not so sure how to compute the integral.

Comment: Please use LaTeX when writing mathematics in this site. In the FAQ section you'll find directions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is enough to assume the line is the unit disk's boundary (i.e. $\,S^1\,$) (why?) , so let us parametrize this as usual:

$$x=\cos t\;,\;\;y=\sin t\;,\;\;t\in [0,2\pi]\;,\;\;dx=-\sin t\,dt\;,\;\;dy=\cos t\,dt\;,\;x^2+y^2=1\,,$$

and then

$$\int\limits_{S^1}\frac{-y^3}{(x^2+y^2)^2} dx + \frac{xy^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} dy=\int\limits_0^{2\pi}\left[(-\sin^3t)(-\sin t\,)+\cos t\sin^2t(\cos t)\right]dt=$$

$$=\int\limits_0^{2\pi}\left(\sin^4x+\sin^2t\cos^2t\right)dt=\int\limits_0^{2\pi}\sin^2tdt=$$

$$=\left.\frac{t-\sin t\cos t}{2}\right|_0^{2\pi}=\pi$$

Comment: Why did you assume the line is the unit disk boundary?

Comment: Because it's easier...:) But, if it is *any* other line enclosing a simply conn. region with the unit disk within it we can always restrict to this case: just join the line with $\,S^1\,$ by a straight line, which you'll "walk" in both directions (one in and one out) and thus its contribution will vanish...! And, of course, check the given field is conservative between $\,S^1\,$ and the original line and thus the integral vanishes there...